# Composition structure on ${\bf Fun}$

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

Let **Fun** denote the category of functors and natural transformations. Does composition of functors together with the [Godement product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Godement+product) of natural transformations amount to some sort of canonical structure on **Fun**?

**Fun** naturally has products inherited from **Cat**, and composition isn't a tensor product that I can see since trivially not all functors can be composed. Is it some other sort of named, more local structure?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the category of functors between two fixed categories?

Comment: @asdq No, the category whose objects are arbitrary functors and whose arrows are natural transformations. You can obtain functor categories between two fixed categories $C$ and $D$ by taking the full subcategory of ${\bf Fun}$ whose objects are functors with domain $C$ and codomain $D$.

Comment: @asdq You can also view ${\bf Fun}$ as the 'top two layers' of the $2$-category of categories, or the coproduct of every functor category between arbitrary fixed categories.

Comment: What do you mean by 'tensor product' in $Cat$?

Comment: @Berci Ah, I was implicitly thinking of categories enriched over groups. I'll edit, thank you.

Comment: Why not just talk about the 2-category of categories, functors, and natural transformations?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm interested in how much of $2$-category theory we can 'study' from a $1$-categorical perspective, as a lark. More generally, I'd like to understand parts of $3$-category theory by studying the bicategory of pseudofunctors, pseudonatural transformations and modifications, so on and so forth at higher levels.

Comment: I do think the correct “named, more local” structure is “a 2-category”, though. Consider the lower-lever example of the class of all functions and their partial composition structure. That’s literally the definition of the category of sets in object-free foundations!

Comment: @KevinArlin I agree that 2-categories are a nice way to name what's going on, but that kind of misses the point of my question. Take the definition you give of the category of sets; it is true that if someone asked "what should we call the class of all functions with partial composition structure" a valid answer would be "the category of sets", however if the someones goal was to study categories by inspecting sets and functions this wouldn't help much since it's saying to study sets and functions by studying categories.

Comment: @AlecRhea Ok, I guess I have no idea what you’re going for then. I don’t know what you mean by “study categories by studying sets and functions” in any concrete sense that doesn’t collapse to something you’re apparently trying to avoid.

Comment: @KevinArlin The goal is to study the categorical hierarchy 'from the bottom up', instead of the top down as is standard in the field. I agree that bicategories form a nice framework for studying categories, and Gray-categories form a nice framework for studying bicategories, etc., but each time we're using something more complicated to study something simpler. I'm curious if we can coherently study the more complicated stuff using the simpler stuff.